# Java naming convention with acronyms

Tags: java, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Naming Convention with Acronyms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236807/java-naming-convention-with-acronyms)

Is it getXml() or getXML()? Is there any official Sun/Oracle document on this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699944/what-is-correct-java-naming-convention-for-id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct. Use your preferred way, and be consistent with it throughout your code.

Answer (score 4):

You'll [find](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html) [both](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html) in the Java Standard API, so if there is a convention, it's not being widely followed.

Comment: Yeah that's why I wanted to see if there's some 'official' convention. I find it quite annoying, but perhaps I'm just being too pedantic.

Answer (score 2):

[Not specified](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

> Except for variables, all instance,
>   class, and class constants are in
>   mixed case with a lowercase first
>   letter. Internal words start with
>   capital letters. Variable names should
>   not start with underscore _ or dollar
>   sign $ characters, even though both
>   are allowed.