# Google App Engine Query Execute only takes 3 arguments

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Can anyone tell me why the following code is causing an error on the last line with the command "execute" with the error message:

> The method execute(Object, Object, Object) in the type Query is not applicable for the arguments (Long, Long, Date, Date)

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(Appointment.class,"AdminID == AID"+
  " && EmployeeID == CEID"+
  " && Time > STime"+
  " && Time < ETime");
q.declareImports("import java.util.Date");
q.declareParameters("Long AID, Long CEID, Date STime, Date ETime");
q.setOrdering("Time");
Appointments = (List<Appointment>) q.execute(AdminID, CurrentEmployeeID, Time1, Time2);
```

As far as I can tell (implied by the error message, the execute function can only take a maximum of 3 arguements, if this is the case, can anyone advise on how to achieve what I want to do? I have tried the following code, but I get a parsing error every time it runs!

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(Appointment.class,"AdminID == "+AdminID+
  " && EmployeeID == "+CurrentEmployeeID+
  " && Time > "+Time1+
  " && Time < "+Time2);
q.declareImports("import java.util.Date");
q.setOrdering("Time");
Appointments = (List<Appointment>) q.execute();
```

The Parsing error I get is:

> org.datanucleus.store.query.QueryCompilerSyntaxException: Portion of expression could not be parsed: Aug 13 11:44:55 BST 2012 && Time < Mon Aug 13 11:45:05 BST 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [executeWithArray](http://db.apache.org/jdo/api30/apidocs/javax/jdo/Query.html#executeWithArray%28java.lang.Object...%29) or [executeWithMap](http://db.apache.org/jdo/api30/apidocs/javax/jdo/Query.html#executeWithMap%28java.util.Map%29).

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put( "AID", adminId );
params.put( "CEID", currentEmployeeId );
params.put( "STime", startTime );
params.put( "ETime", endTime );

query.executeWithMap( params );
```

Notes:

1. variables should be lowerCamelCase
2. `startTime` and `endTime` are more descriptive than `Time1`, `Time2`
3. "Id" is generally preferred over "ID" - [What is correct Java naming convention for id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699944/what-is-correct-java-naming-convention-for-id)
4. your second attempt won't work because it's implicitly calling `..." && Time > " + Time1.toString() + ...`

Comment: Ah, thanks, well thats one part of the problem solved then... so now just looking for another way to do the query with 4 parameters!

Comment: Read up on executeWithArray and executeWithMap.  You probably want executeWithMap( { "AID": AdminID, "CEID": CurrentEmployeeID, "STime": Time1, "ETime": Time2} );